# Почему программа не выходит из цикла при заполнении массива

Tags: c, массивы

Почему при заполнении массива больше чем 11 элементов цикл продолжает работать, хотя должен выйти при введении больше чем длина массива.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int lastchar = 0;
    int stop = 0;


    while(stop != 1){
        arr[lastchar] = getchar();
        if(arr[lastchar] == '\n')
            stop = 1;
        else
            lastchar = lastchar + 1;
        if(lastchar == arr[10])
            stop = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Больше всего меня интересует строчка ```if(lastchar == arr[10]) stop = 1;``` Почему она не работает?

Comment: У вас в массиве 10 элементов то есть индекс последнего это 9, т.к. отсчет начинается с 0. Если вы хотите сделать выход из цикла когда заполнится весь массив, то нужно писать не `lastchar == arr[10]` а `lastchar == 10`

Comment: Небольшой совет: попробуйте для `arr` использовать тип `int`, а для `stop` – `bool`. Не то чтобы это очень влияло на работоспособность данного конкретного приложения, но так будет явно логичнее, чем вводить переменную типа `int` с помощью `getchar()` (слово `char` там не случайно).

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Ничего не получилось даже при `lastchar == 10`, все ровно массив заполняется явно больше 10 элементов.

Comment: @user1 как понять "явно больше 10 элементов"? Ничего не понял если честно. Вы в `int arr[]` записываете 1 символ из консоли. 1 символ, не цифру, а именно символ, я надеюсь вы это понимаете.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Да там хоть символы пиши хоть цифры все ровно, в строку можно писать сколько угодно хоть символов, хоть цифр пока не перейдешь на новую строку. Только тогда программа завершается.

Comment: @user1 по другому никак, если только не вводить каждый символ отдельно нажимая каждый раз на `enter`.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Ясно, спасибо